# Science stack exchanges helping other science stack exchanges!

Tags: discussion, area51

The Physics Meta promotes support for all Science sites on Stack Exchange, in [this](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/915/consider-supporting-proposals-of-other-se-science-sites) post.

The Chemistry SE was one of the sites that benefited from this (if you look at edit 11 of the above linked meta post, you will see that this meta post helped the Chemistry SE proposal to get attention when it needed it in the early days of its proposal in Area51).

Let's give back to the younger science communities, now that we here at Chemistry have graduated out of Beta.

Below is the post from the Physics Meta.

Comment: Congrats on the new logo for Matter Modelling SE :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Science proposals need your help! Consider committing to these, to make them successful & scientific:

See also the long list of [science](https://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/7/science) and [technology](https://area51.stackexchange.com/categories/8/technology) proposals on Area 51.

## Committers needed

- currently none

## Site definition needed

- currently none

## Sites in beta

[image: History of Science and Methematics]
[image: Operations Research]
[image: Earth Science]
[image: Mathematics Educators]
[image: Open Data]

[image: Matter Modeling]
[image: Astronomy]
[image: Engineering]
[image: Robotics]

Comment: It's probably not the best style to use referrer-links in this post. Also, for the sake of maintainability the entries should use inline notation of links `[![alt](img)](click-through)`.